# Use javascript to calculate div height as a percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After some searching I've come across code similar to the demo below that uses js to calculate the height of a div and then sets that number as a margin top to the div below.

This works fine however I need it to calculate as a percentage rather than a 'px' as when I scale down and the responsive image gets smaller the margin-top obviously doesn't scale with it. I'm not sure if this is possible or how I would achieve it?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/9/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  var fixedHeight = $(".fixed-container").outerHeight(true);
  $(".scrolling-container").css({"float":"left", "margin-top":
  fixedHeight + "px"});
});
```

Any suggestions or solutions would be most appreciated.

Comment: I guess you should change the event instead px to % .. such as Window resizeTo()

Comment: Thanks for your response when you do that its calculating the height of the image which is 256px and I think its just converting that to a % of 256% which is why it gets pushed down really low. See http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/6/

Comment: Do I have to add some sort of a calculation so that it converts it to a percentage instead of pixels?

Comment: No, I think you didn't read my comment.. i said try changing javascript event.. from $(document).ready(..)  to Window resizeTo()

Comment: That doesn't seem to work could you explain further?

Comment: hope my answer help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a percentage if you're using jQuery.  Use `$(window).resize()` to update it any time the window updates.

The other reason you can't use a percentage on the height is that you have no container that has a set height.  This means it's going to be a percentage of the entire page.  The more content you add, the bigger the margin will be.  Use this code to achieve what you're doing:

```
function extraMargin() {
    var xMar = $('.fixed-container').outerHeight(); 
    $('.scrolling-container').css({"margin-top":xMar+"px"});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    extraMargin();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    extraMargin();
});
```

This will run `extraMargin()` function when the page loads and when the page is resized.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/10/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explaining clearly. I think this is what I need, I'll test it out and accept your answer as soon as i get it working in my site. Many thanks.

Comment: @user2498890 No problem!  Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: I do have one question - on page load the scrolling-container div is sitting on top of the fixed div. If I then scale the browser down it goes to where I need it to be. How would I do it so that the scrolling-container starts underneath the fixed-container, before the browser changes in size?

Comment: @user2498890 Do you mean like the scrolling div and margin are layered on top of the fixed div?  Like you can not click on the fixed div?  Or do you mean the function is not working on page load? If they are layered improperly, you can give your fixed div a z-index of 1 `z-index:1` and it will layer over anything that doesn't have a z-index in the same container

Comment: I think the function isn't working on page load if you take  a look in the fiddle you created you'll see that on load the text in the scrolling-container is up on top of the fixed-container. I need it to be sat underneath the fixed-container like it is when the window is resized.

Comment: Does that make sense? Sorry if I'm not explaining clearly.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  It works in the fiddle just fine for some reason. But try using '$(window).load' instead of document ready

Comment: `$(window).load` seems to have sorted it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @user2498890, I'm glad it works!  For pictures, or other things that load after the DOM loads, it's best to use `$(window).load`.  It differs from `$(document).ready` in that it waits for the window to draw everything, rather than waiting for the document (DOM) to load.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following steps work if i understand your problem in right way .

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var fixedHeight = $(".fixed-container").outerHeight(true);
     fixedHeight = (fixedHeight/screen.height)*100
    $(".scrolling-container").css("margin-top", fixedHeight + "%");
});
```

Comment: While this is technically what the OP asked for it doesn't have the desired result as the `margin` does not scale with `.fixed-container`. http://jsfiddle.net/dvorskqj/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't seem to work. It just overlaps the fixed div and doesn't scale with it.

Comment: When you view the jsFiddle in my question are you seeing the image?

Comment: did you tested on your device or jsfiddle . For js fiddle it will not works because it will calculates based on device height . And the margin-top was applying from root element .

Answer (score 0):

Actually repeat the complete code on resize window function too:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   var fixedHeight = $(".fixed-container").outerHeight(true);
  $(".scrolling-container").css({"float":"left", "margin-top":fixedHeight + px"});
});
```